# JsonObjectRequest Always returns on ErrorResponse

Tags: java, android, jsonobjectrequest

JsonObjectRequest Always returns onErrorResponse in android

```
public void clickFind(final View view) {
    EditText find = (EditText) findViewById((R.id.editText));
  //  String
   web = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=" + find.getText();
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, web, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("value");

                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                RowItem ri = null;
                 URL newurl = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    try {
                        newurl = new URL(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image"));
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ri = new RowItem(newurl,jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name")
                         ,jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("summary"));


                }

                CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(view.getContext(),R.layout.cf, ri);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "error to upload "+web, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);

} }
```

For example:
http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=bob

Which brings reply but run of6 android phone is always falling on error
Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, web, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            try {
                whichList++;
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                RowItem ri[] = new RowItem[response.length()];


                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonArray = response.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("show");
                    ri[i] = new RowItem(jsonArray.getString("id"), "", "", jsonArray.getJSONObject("image").getString("medium"), jsonArray.getString("name")
                            , jsonArray.getString("summary"));


                }

                ArrayAdapterItem adapter = new ArrayAdapterItem(view.getContext(), R.layout.cf, ri);

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "error to upload " + web, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the documentation, [getJSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray, or
>   throws otherwise.

and inspecting the response from that api endpoint "value" does not seem to exist. I hope I'm not wrong but I can't find any property named "value".

Comment: If this result is what I have my place in the i register
JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject (i);
I mean this site results http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls

Answer (score 0):

The response from http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=bob is a JSON Array and not JSONObject. So you need to use `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`  like this -

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, web,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {

                    for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);//This is your Json object which you can parse now.
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                 Context context = view.getContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "error to upload "+web, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: תרגם

אם זו התוצאה שלי מה אני צריכה  לרשום במקום ה i
JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);


If this result is what I have my place in the i register
JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject (i);

Comment: show: {
id: 139,
url: "http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/139/girls",
name: "Girls",
type: "Scripted",
language: "English",
genres: [
"Drama",
"Romance"
],
status: "Running",
runtime: 30,
premiered: "2012-04-15",
schedule: {
time: "22:00",
days: [
"Sunday"
]
},
rating: {
average: 6.3
},
weight: 1,
network: {
id: 8,
name: "HBO",
country: {
name: "United States",
code: "US",
timezone: "America/New_York"
}
},
webChannel: null,
externals: {
tvrage: 30124,
thetvdb: 220411,
imdb: "tt1723816"

Comment: I told you that the your response is JSON array. You have to to the parse it the way I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: But it makes an error on the i in JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: response.getJSONObject(/*need string not int*/)

Comment: You are not following my answer. In my answer `response` is `JSONArray` and it won't give you any such errors. I guess you are operating on `JSONObject`.